# Converter Excel (.xls) em (.htm)?

Tags: php, html, conversão-de-tipo, xls

Fiz um sistema para uma escola, onde a partir do arquivo em Excel, onde estão armazenados todos os boletins da escola, eu exporto para `.htm`, onde gera alguns arquivos com com essa extensão e a partir dai consigo fazer o recorte dos boletins e comparando com o nome dos alunos que estão no banco de dados. Porém, queria fazer esse processo de exportação automaticamente.
É possível realizar essa operação?

A imagem abaixo são os arquivos gerados após a exportação de um arquivo do Excel(`.xls`). No caso exitem vários desses arquivos, porque o arquivo de origem, no formato excel, possuía varias "guias de navegação". E o conteúdo desses arquivos é o formato `.html` tradicional...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: dê uma olhada nesse site e veja se ajuda você. http://www.fatbellyman.com/webstuff/xml_to_html/

Comment: Não ajuda muito, porque no meu caso é xls extensão do arquivo do excel...

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi muito bem sua dúvida. Você hoje faz a exportação de XLS para HTML manualmente?

Comment: Isso, queria saber se existe a maneira de fazer por código...

Comment: Eu não entendi o porquê de vc fazer isso via PHP. O usuário usa um site, ou usa diretamente o Excel? A sua pergunta poderia ser mais clara.

Comment: A minha pergunta é para facilitar o processo,  visto que o sistema que criei, pega os arquivo html, e faz os recortes dos boletins, que estão nesses vários arquivos. O sistema identifica, o nome do alno de acordo com o banco, e faz um recorte da tabela de inicio ao fim do boletim de um unico aluno individualmente. Porém, fiz o sistema para upload desses multiplos arquivos como esta na foto, mas quem esta utilizando o sistema achou dificil, porque tem que exportar o arquivo primeiro e fazer o upload de todos os arquivo. Ai enviar o arquivo xls, e fazer essas exportaçao por código facilitaria...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Faça download da classe no [repositório do GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).

A classe php e suas dependências estão na pasta `Classes`.

---

#### Exemplo de uso

Aqui é feito a leitura [dessa planilha](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7woUszm3fG7Vnc0STlWUUNUU00/view?usp=sharing) e gerado uma tabela em `HTML`.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

    $arquivo = 'exemplo.xls';

    $tipo = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($arquivo);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($tipo);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($arquivo);

    $planilha = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $ultimaLinha = $planilha->getHighestRow();
    $ultimaColuna = $planilha->getHighestColumn();

    // gera o html
    $html = "<table>";

    // loop em todas as linhas
    for ($linha = 1; $linha <= $ultimaLinha; $linha++) {
        $html .= "<tr>";

        // obtem todos os campos da linha
        $camposLinha = $planilha->rangeToArray("A$linha:$ultimaColuna$linha", NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
        $camposLinha = $camposLinha[0];

        // loop em todos os campos da linha
        for ($campo = 0; $campo < count($camposLinha); $campo++) {
            $html .= "<td>" . $camposLinha[$campo] . "</td>";
        }

        $html .= "</tr>";
    }

    $html .= "</table>";

    // convertendo para HTML.

    $handle = fopen("exemplo.html", "w");
    fwrite($handle, $html);
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

---

[Aqui](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/packages/PHPExcel.html) você pode ver toda a **API** do PHPExcel.

Comment: Perfeito Amigo, demorei para testar porque estava trabalhando em outro projeto, e iria comentar o que faltou, mas você editou e colocou certinho. Era essa resposta que eu esperava :)